# Not Able to Assign value to file uploade control in mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Not Able to Assign value to file uploade control in mvc

```
<li class="lifile">
 <input type="file" id="fileToUpload" name="file" value="@ViewBag.msg" />
 <span class="field-validation-error" id="spanfile"></span>
 </li>
```

Comment: You cannot assign a value to a file input for security reasons. The only way it can be set if by the user selecting a file in the browser

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set a value to a file input in HTML?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1696877/how-to-set-a-value-to-a-file-input-in-html)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot assign Value to input type = file, for Security Reasons

Maybe This will help
[How to set a value to a file input in HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1696877/how-to-set-a-value-to-a-file-input-in-html)

Comment: but i want to Update data and  i m not able to see  that data in file upload control

Comment: what do u want to do exactly ? do u want to just get the name of the uploaded file

Comment: if Yes maybe This will help

Comment: http://www.tutorialrepublic.com/faq/how-to-get-selected-file-name-from-input-type-file-using-jquery.php